# Can I reuse the same radiobutton with same value for different section?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

As shown in the image below I am using radio buttons for collecting feedback from the user. Do I need to give unique names to all those 8 buttons to fetch the data? Or is there any other convenient way to declare only 4 buttons and reuse them in every section?

Please view this image for better understanding:
[image: Please view this image for better understanding]

Comment: https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create a method to put the eligible radio buttons in one sequence, you don't need the names. You can use LINQ to get the one that is selected:

```
private IEnumerable<RadioButton> RadioButtons => ...

private RadioButton SelectedRadioButton => this.RadioButtons
    .Where(radioButton => radioButton.Checked)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

One method would be to get all radio buttons in one control (for instance a GroupBox)

```
IEnumerable<RadioButton> GetRadioButtons(Control control)
{
    return control.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>();
}
```

If all RadioButtons have the same event handler, then you can use parameter sender:

```
private void OnRadioButtonCheckedChange(object sender, ...)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
    if (radioButton.Checked)
        this.RadioButtonSelected(radioButton);
    else
        this.RadioButtonDeselected(radioButton);
}
```